# XPath: How do I capture the previous element?

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have such a construction

```
<p>File name</p>
<a href="https://somelink.pdf">Download</a>
```

I need to capture the link `a` and its name `p` using CSS and XPath. I'm trying to do the following, first I find using the CSS selector all files whose `href` values end in `.pdf` (`a[href$=".pdf"]`):

```
for i in response.css('a[href$=".pdf"]'):
    link = i.css('::attr("href")').get()
    name = i.xpath(?????????)
    print(name, link)
```

How do I capture the text in the `p` element using XPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Starting from `a`

This XPath,

```
//a[.="Download"]/preceding-sibling::p[1]
```

will select the first `p` element siblings preceding each `a` element whose string value equals `"Download"`.

---

### Starting from `p`

This XPath,

```
//p[.="File name"]/following-sibling::a[1]
```

will select the first `a` element siblings following each `p` element whose string value equals `"File name"`.

---

In either case, you can select the text node child by appending `/text()` to the XPaths.